# How to use Dragon's Dogma save to start new game with bonuses in Dark Arisen?

Tags: dragons-dogma-dark-arisen

I had Dragon's Dogma, played a bit, then sold it when I realized I wanted Dark Arisen.  Then, Dark Arisen came to PS+ and I was in luck!  However, it is not all luck.  When I sold Dragon's Dogma, I also deleted my save file.  I didn't think it mattered since I had barely played, my character was ugly, and I just wanted to start fresh.

In Dark Arisen, I still want to start fresh, but I also know you get bonuses if you have a Dragon's Dogma save file.  I can download a Dragon's Dogma save, but will that prevent me from starting at the beginning?  How can I start at the beginning and get the bonuses?

I hope this makes sense.  The save in question I'll be using is downloadable from Gamefaqs.  Maybe it's not possible to start a new game with an old save file, though.  Help!